# Must I escape every '\' to realize vim substitution of file path?

Tags: vim

I need to substitute a long path to a brief new pattern. I feel like escape every `\` a dumb idea, it looks like:

```
:%s/\/my\/very\/very\/dumb\/long\/path\//new_pattern/gc
```

Is there a smarter way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Must I escape every '\' to realize vim substitution of file path?

No, you don't.

> Is there a smarter way to do that?

Yes. You can use a different character after `%s`.

```
:%s+/my/very/very/dumb/long/path+new_pattern+gc
```

From `:help :s`

> Instead of the `'/'` which surrounds the pattern and replacement string, you
>   can use any other single-byte character, but not an alphanumeric character,
>   `'\'`, `'"'` or `'|'`.  This is useful if you want to include a `'/'` in the search
>   pattern or replacement string. Example:

```
:s+/+//+
```

Comment: Got it, so it means I can use `pseudo-arbitrary` separate symbol in vim substitution such as in `sed` command?

Comment: @Zen, yes, within the limitations described in the help section.